# IE11 iFrame click event bubbles up to affect window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, frontend

To my understanding, an event can be prevented from bubbling up by returning false(or using `event.stopPropagation()`).

I have bound a click event to my anchor tag, so that when it is clicked, the  is now loaded into the element using jQuery's `.html()`.

All this works fine on all browsers except for IE. On IE11, the first click works and loads up the iframe but any subsequent clicks on the iframe (i.e., to "click to pause" or increasing the volume" seem to bubble up and trigger the `href="#"` which scrolls the page to the top.

I have read that it is bad practice to use `href="#"` in an anchor tag that does not redirect and what to do instead. I agree with that suggestion, but I really would like to know why the click on the iframe seems to still have an effect on the page.

I added some code 'register()` to show that the context was different for window and iframe.

What is going on in IE11 and how can it be prevented (without removing href), if possible? Thanks

```js
var $, bind, page_click, reg;
$ = jQuery;

bind = function() {
    $(".video").click(function(e) {
        var el, video;
        el = $(e.target);
        while (el.prop("tagName") !== "A") {
            el = el.parent();
        }
        video = '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/160755996?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0" width="500" height="264" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'
        el.empty().html(video);
        return false;
    });
}

// test code to show that clicking in the iframe's context is indeed not same 
// as the current window
page_click = function(e) {
    alert("page_click");
};

// capture all click events on the window
register = function() {
    window.captureEvents(Event.CLICK);
    return window.onclick = page_click;
};

bind();
register()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 class="class">Hello Plunker!</h1>
      
        <div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed iaculis, 
      erat quis eleifend accumsan, justo nisl porttitor ante, a pretium ex enim id 
      mauris. Suspendisse non vehicula nibh. Phasellus vitae consectetur est, id 
      condimentum metus. Etiam placerat hendrerit erat et interdum. Nulla convall
      is rhoncus volutpat. Aliquam iaculis, velit id iaculis semper, diam nulla 
      hendrerit sem, vitae pellentesque elit felis eu eros. Praesent id viverra tortor. 
      Donec vel rhoncus arcu. Donec ut fringilla mi. Nulla vestibulum viverra odio 
      vel ullamcorper. In vulputate nunc mattis tellus vehicula, sit amet commodo
      metus ornare. Quisque pretium ligula dolor, et lacinia ligula lacinia in.
      Aenean vitae ex quis erat tincidunt elementum a ac sem. Nulla vel placerat neque. 
      Nam vitae euismod quam.
  
      Donec vitae nibh nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras eget dolor porta,
      fringilla magna in, congue augue. Suspendisse scelerisque diam at ligula 
      vulputate egestas. Sed vitae metus neque. Praesent sed lacus blandit, 
      hendrerit libero non, maximus metus. Phasellus interdum erat dictum, rhoncus
      lectus in, tincidunt leo. Quisque bibendum pellentesque ipsum et elementum.
  
      Vivamus dictum condimentum lacus non vulputate. Etiam pulvinar eu magna id
      lacinia. Phasellus efficitur placerat ante, in faucibus mauris elementum ut. 
      Nam dui quam, euismod ac sem at, feugiat porttitor ex. Donec id felis est.
      Aenean euismod nibh ut sem interdum, et ullamcorper lorem condimentum. 
      Pellentesque dictum commodo blandit. Curabitur eu felis sed dui vulputate 
      ullamcorper non nec odio. Nulla urna purus, hendrerit non malesuada in,
      consequat quis nunc. Mauris finibus turpis in turpis egestas, vitae ornare 
      ante tempus. Suspendisse eu dapibus mi, id aliquam arcu. Aliquam gravida 
      rutrum ullamcorper. Proin ultrices lectus eu velit imperdiet, vitae aliquam 
      ante venenatis. Maecenas ullamcorper quis urna sit amet efficitur. 
      Proin consectetur vehicula elit eget tincidunt.
  
      Aenean accumsan tempus tellus feugiat cursus. Praesent pulvinar finibus ligula,
      nec ornare lorem posuere id. Duis condimentum tempor scelerisque. Nullam ante 
      sem, maximus ac malesuada a, eleifend id felis. Phasellus gravida dui et nibh 
      laoreet bibendum. Aliquam vulputate nulla in nisl accumsan porta. Praesent feugiat, 
      diam et faucibus porta, odio orci egestas lorem, ac posuere nunc mauris id ipsum. 
      Curabitur porta tempor felis, ut pellentesque arcu dictum et. Nunc quis felis 
      risus. Praesent sed fermentum nisi, ut bibendum felis. Integer velit sapien,
      hendrerit ac erat quis, porta tempus sapien. Integer mattis posuere dolor 
      vitae luctus. Cras commodo elementum ligula at imperdiet. Nullam efficitur 
      metus eget volutpat aliquet.
  
      Morbi ac erat a sem convallis convallis at non magna. Cras nec lectus consequat 
      est auctor vestibulum et non metus. Sed luctus lacinia elit, ut ultricies ante 
      venenatis vitae. Ut pellentesque est eget placerat tincidunt. Pellentesque molestie 
      id ligula fringilla pellentesque. Praesent viverra ipsum in mi facilisis dapibus. 
      Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus efficitur 
      augue in lectus rhoncus, eu faucibus ex ornare. Aliquam sodales tincidunt ante, 
      nec cursus velit rutrum et. Donec sagittis ullamcorper tortor eget interdum.
      Aliquam efficitur, metus in feugiat condimentum, ligula orci tristique eros, 
      ut rhoncus sapien risus vitae leo.
      </div>
        <a class="video" href="#">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="">
        </a>
      
        <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I have created this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ds82u6B8wsDj3U92TZHL?p=preview://) to help demonstrate the issue I am experiencing.

Comment: It's because you are placing the iframe inside the link (which is not even valid in HTML.) Just place it outside of the link, or replace the link with it.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thanks, @CBroe. Would you mind going into a bit more detail as why this is not considered valid HTML? Thanks once again.

Comment: I’ve added an answer with some more information.

Comment: Did you really need to paste all that text here? I mean it's not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are placing the iframe inside the link (which is not even valid in HTML.) Just place it outside of the link, or replace the link with it.

---

As to why this is not valid HTML:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element describes the Content Model (what you can put inside of it) for the `a` element as:

> Transparent, but there must be no [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.

And there under that second link it says,

> **Interactive content** is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
>   ⇒ a, audio (if the controls attribute is present), button, embed, iframe, img (if the usemap attribute is present), input (if the type attribute is not in the Hidden state), keygen, label, object (if the usemap attribute is present), select, textarea, video (if the controls attribute is present)

So, `a` is not allowed to contain `iframe`, amongst other things.

Basically this requirement is to avoid any ambiguity that could arise, if such elements that are intended for user interaction *would* be nested.

Imagine a simple form, and inside it a link that points to `https://www.google.com`, and *inside* that link was a submit button for the form. Now what should happen, when the user clicks that button? Should it submit the form? Should it not submit the form, but go to Google instead? (Both at the same time would not be possible, the browser can make only one “main” request at a time.)